# What is the most general form of Hurwitz's theorem in complex analysis?

Tags: cv.complex-variables

In complex analysis, Hurwitz's  theorem  roughly states that, under certain conditions, if a sequence of holomorphic functions converges uniformly to a holomorphic function on compact sets, then after a while  (above a certain rank ) those functions and the limit function have the same number of zeros  in any open disk.

I read somewhere that the result is valid more generally on bounded convex sets , from what I remember, but no references were given.

Question. Where can I find this more general statement of Hurwitz's theorem, and where can I find some useful references in this direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has nothing to do with convexity. The exact formulation is this:

Let $\Omega$ be an arbitrary region, and $f_n\to f$ is a sequence of holomorphic functions converging uniformly on compacts in $\Omega$.
If $f\neq 0$ (this is an important condition!), and $D$ is a region,
such that $\overline{D}\subset \Omega$, and $f(z)\neq 0$ on $\partial D_1$, then there exists $N$ (dependng on $D$) such that for $n\geq N$, $f$ and $f_n$ have the same number of zeros
in $D$.

For the proof, you find an intermediate region $D_1$ such that
$D\subset D_1\subset\overline{D_1}\subset\Omega$, and $\partial D_1$ is piecewise smooth, and the number of zeros of $f$ in $\overline{D_1}$ is the same as the number of zeros in $D$. Such region exists since $\overline{D}\subset\Omega$, and since the zeros
of $f$ are isolated and $f(z)\neq 0,\; z\in\partial D$.
Then the number
of zeros $f$ in $D$ is the same as in $D_1$ and is equal to
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D_1} \frac{df}{f},$$
and the number of zeros of $f_n$ in $D_1$ is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D_1} \frac{df_n}{f_n}.$$
Since $f_n\to f$ uniformly on the compact set $K:=\overline{D_1}\backslash D$, and $f(z)\neq 0$ on $K$, we conclude that for $n\geq N$, $f_n$ has the same number of zeros
in $D$ and $D_1$. Since the integrals for $f_n^\prime/f_n$ converge to the
integral for $f'/f$, and all these integrals are integers, we conclude that they are equal for $n\geq N$.

Refs. This is stated in full generality in the book

A. I. Markushevich, Theory of functions of a complex variable,
vol. I, Ch. IV, Sect 3 (p. 426 of the Russian original).

Special cases are in:

Ahlfors, Complex Analysis, p. 178, Theorem 2,

Titchmarsh, The theory of functions, sect. 3.45,

Marshall, Complex Analysis, Theorem 8.8,

But all these special cases have the same proof as the general theorem whose complete proof I wrote.

Comment: The condition that $f$ has no zeros on $\delta D$ is necessary, right?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko     I suspect the condition is that f doesn't vanish on the boundary of D1, and it's implied by the condition that f doesn't vanish on K.

Comment: I think that one can only say that for every zero of $f$ inside $D$ there are close zeroes (adding up to the multiplicity of the zero of $f$)  of $f_n$ inside $D$ for large enough $n$, but $f_n$ can have zeroes that converge to the boundary of $D$ (so they give zeroes of $f$ on the boundary) as something like $1-z, 1-(1+1/n)z$ on the unit disc shows as $f_n$ has zeroes $\frac{n}{n+1}$ but $f$ has no zeroes inside the unit disc

Comment: There is a simple counterexample: $f_n(z)=z+(-1)^n\frac{1}{n}$ and $D$ is the disk $|z+1|<1$

Comment: The mistake is in the assumption that $f$ has the same number of zeros in $D$ and in $D_1$. That's not true, if there are zeros on the boundary.

Comment: @Oleg Eroshkin: Thanks, I corrected the mistake.